# Why is my gallery app (designed using Glide) taking nearly 500mb RAM

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-glide, android-memory

I made a gallery app which show offline stored images using GLIDE library in recyclerView but when i view the **Profiler in android Studio it shows me that the app is taking nearly 500mb memory.** Is this normal that my app is taking this much memory.

However my app is not crashing but it hang sometimes while showing images and also images are load all togethor (i can see the size of scrollbar getting smaller)

Also after asking User-permission **images are not shown** instantly. I have to start the app again to view these images. Those images should have been visible after accepting the permission.

[image: This is the normal look of my app] 
[image: Sometime when scrolling some white space also come between the images.]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7onom.jpg)This is the normal look of my app.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jziR0m.jpg)Sometime when scrolling some white space also come between the images (shown in brown shaped oval).

for reducing the memory, I tried to decrease the height of the imageView (thinking that may be now glide had to load less pixels) but didn't work at all.
for user-permission i tried using Android Developers Guide but still no luck.

```
// this is my main activity
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 100;
    private Cursor mCursor=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // layout initialization code
        mCursor = getImageCursor();
        requestStoragePermission();

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.imageRecyclerView);
        mAdapter = new mayankImageAdapter(this,mCursor);

      //..... (setting the recyclerView)
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    private void requestStoragePermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // file-related task you need to do.

                }
                else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }


    public Cursor getImageCursor(){
        try{
            Uri externalUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            String[] projection = new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            String sortOrder = MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE+" ASC";

            Cursor imageCursor = getContentResolver().query(externalUri,
                        projection,null,null,sortOrder);
            return imageCursor;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mCursor.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

mayankImageAdapter.java

```
\\ onBindViewHolder method
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int position) {
        if(imageCursor!=null) {
            imageCursor.moveToFirst();
            imageCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            int strIndex = imageCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

            String str = imageCursor.getString(strIndex);
            File myimageloc = new File(str);
            GlideApp.with(callingActivity).load(myimageloc).into(myViewHolder.imgView); 
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }
```

acitivity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/imageRecyclerView"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

I want to know the reason why my app is taking so much memory and what are steps to decrease this memory and how can i show images just after asking permissions from the user.

Thanks

**Edit: I have updated the user-permission code and RecyclerView adapter code.**

Comment: the app uses a lot of memory because you are directly loading full images from files. when an 1080p image is loaded into a bitmap object, it takes 1080*1920 pixels, and each pixel takes an int for argb8888 config, which is 4 bytes, that makes 8MB memory usage for one image

for a gallery app you should load thumbnails in the grid preview

Comment: So @ssynhtn are recommending that i should load thumbnail into the recycler view and then on clicking a picture i should load the original picture.

Comment: @ssynhtn so i change the cursor as Cursor c = getContentResolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA, null,null,null);  and then in the onbindViewHolder method set strIndex = imageCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.thumbnails.DATA);

But even after doing this profiler is still showing 200mb memory and as scroll fastly the memory usage increases.

Comment: @ssynhtn do you have any idea why images are not loading just after asking user-permissions. At present i have to restart the app to view the images. And also is there any way to get the imageTitle from the thumbnail.

Comment: as for the permission, you should make sure you have been granted the permission before you set up adapter and stuff, by using ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission and in the Activity.onRequestPermissionsResult. In your code I don't see anything similar.

Comment: @ssynhtn actually i have implemented that but i thought that i may not have any problem so i don't copy it.

Comment: Also these thumbnails are not present of all images. for example some of the @ssynhtn images of whatsapp dono't have thumbnails. so how can i show those images which don't have thumbnails. MediaStore.images.thumbnails is only showing thumbnails which are present in DCIM>>.thumbnail.

Comment: Do you have any [glide caching](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html) where the cache size is unlimited (so old cached images are nevewer deleted?

Comment: @k3b i am not using any other statement then the one used in onBindViewHolder method. I am very new to glide so i was not even aware about this.